# Is it possible to upgrade a State Machine?

Tags: statemachines

I wonder if it is possible to design a State Machine that has a special state transition that can upgrade the State Machine, meaning creating a new UTxO sitting at a new script address (instead of the old script address), representing the upgraded State Machine. After the upgrade, future transactions will be validated using the new State Machine.

I am not sure if this upgrading functionality is achievable using State Machine. If so, how can it be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Make a statemachine with a transition "Update".
- Use `Constraints` (or otherwise, eg `check`) to layout in which contexts an "Upgrade" is permissible. For example "must be signed by my special key".
- Make the upgrade target state a final state (`isFinal s == True`)

Et voila. You have "upgraded" your statemachine.

Obvs cardano validators are immutable - you can't upgrade them in the "mutate a thing" way

Comment: Thanks! Your approach will finish the current validator. I think additionally the update transition has to explicitly guarantee the creation of an UTxO sitting on the updated validator, to ensure the updated validator will be available.